# PowerShell Set WebApplication Timeout

Tags: powershell, web-application

How do you change the SPWebApplication Web Page Security Validation timeout via PowerShell.  I want to set this upon creating a web application during the creation of a farm, but I'm happy running a follow up script after creating the farm too.

You get to this in the GUI via Central Admin>Application Management>(select an app)>General Settings>Web Page Security Validation>Security validation expires after: ...

I can see the timeout setting in PowerShell using the scripts below, but I cannot set it that way.  formDigestSettings is read only.  You can leave off the '.Minutes' on the last line for more information about it.

```
$site = get-spsite 'https://....'

$webapp = $site.WebApplication

$webapp.FormDigestSettings.Timeout.Minutes
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$SPSite = Get-SPSite("[URL of site collection]")
$webApp = $SPSite.WebApplication
$webApp.FormDigestSettings.Enabled = $true
$webApp.FormDigestSettings.Expires = $true
$webApp.FormDigestSettings.Timeout = New-TimeSpan -Hours 1 -Minutes 20
$webApp.Update()
```

http://www.eblogin.com/eblogin/post/2011/11/28/SPsecurity_timeout.aspx#.VsTq4vkrKCg

Answer (score 0):

I actually just answered it myself.

Change the last line by adding the specified time in this format:

```
$webapp.FormDigestSettings.Timeout = '00:15:00'
```

Then add another line:

```
$webapp.Update()
```

You can then verify the change with:

```
$webapp.FormDigestSettings.Timeout
```